# Local value for Background and Content property at button control is not set when background and content is specified in Control template

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, controltemplate, operator-precedence

According to Dependency Property Value Precedence,local value has higher precedence compared to control templates .(Refer link https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/ms743230%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

But in my example below,content and background property of button control is set from control template in spite of specifying these properties in control element locally.Background is set Orange and Content as "TemplateContent"

Below is the xaml :

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button"  >            
            <Border CornerRadius="10" Width="100" Height="50" Background="Orange">
                <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="TemplateContent"  />
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

<Button  Template="{StaticResource ButtonTemplate}" Background="Blue" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="LocalContent" Width="100" Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
```

I also understand local values can have impact when templatebinding is used in control template.But why doesn't a local value have impact in spite of having higher order precedence in dependency property value precedence

Comment: You'll need to use template bindings if you want templates to be customizable. Try replacing `Orange` with `{TemplateBinding Background}`. If it has to be orange by default, provide a style that does so - that style can also set the template, so you don't have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the MSDN documentation is not very clear on this point (as is often the case), and you have misunderstood what they mean by "local value".

In your example, the "local value" of concern is the `Border` object's `Background` property assignment in the XAML. And this does indeed take precedence. Even if e.g. a `Style` setter tried to set the value of that property, it would fail, because you have locally set the property value to `"Orange"`.

The `Background="Blue"` for the `Button` element sets the value of *an entirely different property*. I.e. the property of the `Button` object, not of the `Border` object. This assignment will in fact *also* have high precedence, but only over things which might set that specific property (e.g. a `Button` style). It has no effect on an entirely different object contained in the template (i.e. the `Border`).

The `{TemplateBinding ...}` markup exists for this exact purpose. If you declare your template like this:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ButtonTemplate" TargetType="Button">
  <Border CornerRadius="10" Width="100" Height="50"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Content="TemplateContent"/>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Then WPF will know to look to the `TemplatedParent` object, and its `Background` property in particular, to find the value to which to set the `Border.Background` property value.

Comment: Given how precedence works it might be worth noting that the default (orange) should be set via a `Button` style that has a respective `Setter`.

Comment: @H: I agree with your suggestion of usage, but I'm not sure whether adding that to the answer is helpful or not. I think the blue and orange colors in the original question were probably to illustrate clearly that the blue didn't affect the border. I'm not sure the intent was really to provide a default background color of orange (I'm also not sure it _wasn't_). Mainly though I always worry about adding too much detail to answers, risking obfuscation of the primary point. If you have an idea for how to introduce that added information in a clear, confusion-proof way, I'd welcome your edit.